# Focus Parent From Child using React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to focus Parent input box after a Dialog box is popped up. I tried passing Parent's ref to child and focus from child but hard time making it to work.

I'd appreciate your help.

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-components-react-custom-hooks-forked-iyumhx?file=/src/Modal.js

Code:

```
const App = () => {
  const { isShowing, toggle, setIsShowing } = useModal();
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (input != "") setIsShowing(true);
  }, [input]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" ref={ref} onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)} />
      <Modal
        isShowing={isShowing}
        hide={toggle}
        forwardRef={ref}
        input={input}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

here on Console.log ref, I can see the Ref is defined but the `focus` function does not work.

```
const Modal = ({ isShowing, hide, forwardRef, input }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(forwardRef);
    forwardRef.current.focus();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <M
        isOpen={isShowing}
        role="dialog"
        autoFocus={true}
        centered={true}
        size="lg"
        // query={query}
        scrollable={false}
      >
        From Parent {input}
      </M>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put autofocus false on the modal. This will prevent the modal from stealing focus from the input.

Answer (score 2):

Change your modal useEffect to

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (forwardRef.current) {
    forwardRef.current.focus();
  }
}, [forwardRef]);
```

Comment: Does not work sir. . https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-components-react-custom-hooks-forked-iyumhx?file=/src/Modal.js

Comment: Just changed Modal.js to Modal.jsx. Works fine

Comment: Here is your new changes. Does not Work Again. https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-components-react-custom-hooks-forked-iyumhx?file=/src/Modal.jsx

Comment: I am seeing the input field getting focused on mount in sandbox !! You were asking for something different?

Comment: On clicking input field, a modal appears. Once a modal appears, the input field is no longer focused. . So therefore, I wanted to retain the focus of the input field even after the modal is opened up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the modal from reactstrap library has `autoFocus={true}` by default, you have to set it to false, you also don't need help from useRef. here is working code:

App.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Modal from "./Modal";
import "./styles.css";
import { useBoolean } from "./useBoolean";

const App = () => {
  const [isModalOpen, openModal, closeModal] = useBoolean();
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={(e) => {
          if (e.target.value !== "") openModal();
          else closeModal();

          setInputValue(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <Modal isOpen={isModalOpen} inputValue={inputValue} />
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Modal.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Modal as M } from "reactstrap";

const Modal = ({ isOpen, inputValue }) => {
  return (
    <M
      isOpen={isOpen}
      autoFocus={false} // THIS PART WAS THE ISSUE, THIS SHOULD BE FALSE!
      centered={true}
      size="lg"
      scrollable={false}
    >
      Input: {inputValue}
    </M>
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

useBoolean.js

```
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";

export const useBoolean = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(false);
  const onToggleOn = useCallback(() => setValue(true), []);
  const onToggleOff = useCallback(() => setValue(false), []);

  return [value, onToggleOn, onToggleOff];
};
```